# Contact form redirect

Tags: php

I need my thank you page to open in a new tab. Is this possible?

I am new to php and do not know where to begin. I know  `target="_blank"` works for links but I don't know if it would work for this.

```php
<?php
session_start();
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "draw@example.com";
/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$subject = 'I would like to enter the example Draw';
$email    = check_input($_POST['email'], "Enter your email");
$fullname = check_input($_POST['fullname'], "Enter your name");
$headers = "From: $email  <" . $email . ">\r\n";
/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) show_error("E-mail address not valid");
/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website)) $website = '';
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

I would like to enter the example Draw.

Full Name: $fullname

Email: $email

End of message
";
/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

$_SESSION['fullname'] = $_POST['fullname'];
/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location:https://www.example.com/pages/thank-you/draw');
/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0) show_error($problem);

    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get that link to open in a new tab. Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information, like "condition"

Comment: The form is in a pop up. When you fill in the form I would like that page with the pop up form to stay and the thank you page open in a new tab.

Comment: PHP can not do it, you need javascript. Let PHP be used for validation and process using ajax.

Comment: Can you maybe help me with what to search for. Thanks

Comment: Try replacing the header redirect line with this:                                                     `?>
<script>
 window.open("https://www.example.com/pages/thank-you/draw", "_blank");
</script>
<?php`

Answer (score 0):

PHP can not do it, you need JavaScript. I just provide logic, not revise your code.

## Option #1

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kristories/gj2mfsk3/)

```
<!-- Contact button (open popup) -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contact">
    Contact
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-contact" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                Contact form
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                <!-- Send button -->
                <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, you need JavaScript

```
$(function(){

  // Event click, submit or ...
  $('#submit').click(function(){
    // Process (maybe via AJAX)
    // If success, open new tab "thank you page"
    window.open('http://yoursite/thank-you.html', '_blank');
  });

})
```

---

## Option #2

```
<!-- Check when submit (but you need to validate before) -->
<?php if(isset($_POST['fullname']){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('http://yoursite/thank-you.html', '_blank');
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Option #2 where would i put this code in my code. Thanks

Comment: Before `</body>` or in `<head>`

Comment: I did that and now the page shows all white. Thanks

Comment: Show me your full source. I think you have another page before submit email.